# Google calendar & drive sync in Xenial Xerus 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google, online-accounts

After adding my google credentials using online-accounts, I could not get the calendar to sync / see my google drive in the file manager.

Maybe something is broken in the gnome packages ubuntu relies on?